# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1024] at entry 0 and [768] at entry 1

Tags: python

I am a beginner with pytorch. I am trying to do an aspect based sentiment analysis. I am facing the error mentioned in the subject. My code is as follows: I request help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance. I will share the entire code and the error stack. !pip install transformers

```
%%time



pretrained_model = "gpt2"
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '<pad>'})




input_ids = [tokenizer.encode(text, padding='max_length', truncation=True, is_split_into_words=True, add_special_tokens=True) for text in text_data]



input_ids = []
attention_mask = []
max_length = 1024
stride = 256

for text in text_data:
    
    tokens = tokenizer(text, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', truncation=True)
    input_ids.extend(tokens['input_ids'][0, i:i+max_length] for i in range(0, tokens['input_ids'].shape[1], stride))
    attention_mask.extend(tokens['attention_mask'][0, i:i+max_length] for i in range(0, tokens['attention_mask'].shape[1], stride))

input_ids = torch.stack(input_ids)
attention_mask = torch.stack(attention_mask)
input_ids = input_ids[:, :max_length]
attention_mask = attention_mask[:, :max_length]



class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        self.input_ids = input_ids
        self.attention_mask = attention_mask


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input_ids)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return {
            'input_ids': self.input_ids[index],
            'attention_mask': self.attention_mask[index],
        }

train_dataset = CustomDataset(input_ids, attention_mask)



data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)



training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./gpt2_model",  
    overwrite_output_dir=True,   
    num_train_epochs=3,          
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,  
    save_steps=50,           
    save_total_limit=2,         
    prediction_loss_only=True,   
    logging_steps=50,          
    logging_dir="./logs",     

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)


trainer.train()

trainer.save_model("./gpt2_trained_model")
```

And got the results:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1024] at entry 0 and [768] at entry 1
```